# How can I check if an iframe is loaded or not? And how can I interact with the elements within the iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, events, iframe, ecmascript-6

I've approached this much. Now, I see the inner document.

```
var ifrm = document.getElementsByClassName("css-axxz1")[0].children[0];
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
console.log(doc);
doc.onload = function(){
    alert("hi");
};
```

However, I see nothing there.

[image]

So, I added `onload` to make sure it loads completely.

```
var ifrm = document.getElementsByClassName("css-axxz1")[0].children[0];
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
console.log(doc);
doc.onload = function(){
    alert("hi");
};
```

But the result is the same. It's an empty document. And the alert doesn't show up.

And I'd like to add a click listener to the button element in the iframe. Then, get the value of the input element in the iframe.

But the problem is, the button doesn't have ID. But it has class names.

```
<button color="#A13354" data-qa="ok-button-visible deep-purple-ok-button-visible" class="button__Buttoewzc s2sWPP"></button>
```

How can I implement these?

Comment: `document` does'n fire `load` event, attach the listener to `contentWindow` instead. And of course the domains of the main page and the iframe must match, you can't access a third-party document.

Comment: So, I can't give any events in the iframe???

Comment: You can do anything (almost) with the iframe as long as the domain of the src is the same as the domain of the main page. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Could you please tell me whether the iframe loaded is cross domain url? Also please specify if the iframe has sufficient sandbox property passed to it

Comment: iframe loads different domain. And I don't get `sufficient sandbox property`. @prasanakannan

Comment: Ok Thanks. you could use `postMessage` to communicate with the iframe and iframe must receive the script and pass message back. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @prasanakannan, Oh, What I wanna do is adding event listener to inner document on the main document. And getting value from inner document on the main document.

Comment: If it means ur trying to access the same origin URL right ? if so, you could achieve it 
`window.parent.postMessage()` . The link I sent would be helpful. Remember cross-origin  wont work here

Comment: No, different one. A domain for Main doc, B domain for iframe on the Main doc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details, like a codepen or jsfiddle link, without which answering your question is difficult.

However,

I found the following link.

https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/iframe.php

> **Note: These cross-document interactions are only possible if the documents have the same origin. The postMessage method provides the means of interacting cross-domain.**

For more on same origin policy - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

After the above has been solved, you can add a click listener using

`document.getElementsByClassName("button__Buttoewzc")`

Comment: Well, I read the document and implemented, and didn't work as I expected so I posted a question here.

Comment: The first tutorial link only works on the same domain.